# border-top на 50%

Tags: html, css

Нужно как-то указать размер border-top. Ширина блока 300px, border-top должен быть на 150px (50%)
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Ну а сами то пытались сделать? Как успехи? Ладно, так и быть...

```css
div {
  --basesize: 300px;
  width: var(--basesize);
  border-top-width: calc(.5*var(--basesize));
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: +) В любом случае - у ТС есть выбор из множества вариантов

Answer (score 2):

```css
.main {
        border: 3px solid #000;
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
        position:relative;
        padding: 10px
} 
.spoiler {
        position: absolute;
        top:-3px;
        left: -1px;
        width:50%;
        height: 3px;
        background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="spoiler"></div>
        Нужно как-то указать размер border-top. Ширина блока 300px, border-top должен быть на 150px (50%) Как это сделать?
</div>
```

Comment: Кстати да, интересно что имел в виду автор вопроса. )))

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov  - ) Да - мысль такая тоже посетила)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.yourClass{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #09f;
  border-top: 150px solid #000; /* вот что тебе нужно */
}
```

```html
<div class="yourClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй псевдоэлемент с padding'ом:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: silver;
  min-height: 180px;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```